# How to emulate that my computer don't have USB port

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, usb

My application has logic that checks if the computer has USB port. The logic is quite simple:

```
public bool CheckUSBAvailable()
    {
        System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_USBController");
        return (searcher.Get().Count > 0);
    }
```

Is this approach correct for WIndows 7, 8.1 and Windows 10 ?
How can I test this method if its working ? I have Windows 10 and the method always return that I do have USB port, even if I disable all USB devices. Is there is a way how I can test the code ?

Comment: The API looks OK.  You might want to consider testing on a VM.

Comment: Thank you paulsm. Is there a way how to test it on real computer, I don't have a VM?

Comment: Go into device manager and disable all of your USB controllers. I hope you have wireless or PS/2 keyboard and mouse.

Comment: I deleted all of them, but the query still returns that I have 1 USB device

Comment: Are you able to determine from additional code what the device is? It might just be some other USB device you weren't expecting.

Comment: @itsme86 _I hope you have wireless or PS/2 keyboard and mouse._ Yikes!